# How to pass an object or reference to a function?

Tags: c++, function, class, arduino

I want to ask for help in the following ..
How to pass an object or reference to a function?

```
#include <Encoder.h>

// Default Encoder class
Encoder mainEncoder( 2, 3 );

// My class
class MyClass {

  private:
    Encoder *Enc;
    int value;

  public:
    MyClass( Encoder *Enc, int value ) {
      Enc->write( value );
    }

    int read() {
      return Enc->read();
    }

}

// Create..
MyClass Encoder( &mainEncoder, 50 );

// Loop...
int encoderOut = Encoder.read();
```

This way it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Read some good [C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html) then see [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) and read the documentation of your C++ compiler

Comment: By using a class name as variable name (`Encoder`) you are searching for https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mischief. At least, you confuse yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code doesn't initialize `MyClass::Enc` (nor `value`).

A fix:

```
MyClass( Encoder *Enc, int value ) 
    : Enc(Enc) // <---- initialize Enc.
{
    Enc->write(value);
}
```